# ソースコードからインストールしたApacheが起動できない

Tags: centos, apache

大学で現在の時刻を表す動的webページをCGI,Perl,PHP,SSIとJavaScriptそれぞれ一つずつ作りなさいという課題をやった後、apache再起動時に以下のエラーがでました。

```
[root@user1 ~]:501#  /etc/init.d/apache start
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

とりあえず/usr/sbin/lsof -i |grep httpdコマンドでプロセスを調べ、kill -9 ****コマンドで一つずつ削除したところ、再起動できました。

```
[root@user1 ~]:502# /usr/sbin/lsof -i |grep httpd
    httpd    1679   root    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1685 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1686 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1688 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1689 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1690 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1691 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1692 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    1693 apache    3u  IPv4  10333      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
[root@user1 ~]:503# kill -9 1679
[root@user1 ~]:504# kill -9 1685
[root@user1 ~]:505# kill -9 1686
[root@user1 ~]:506# kill -9 1688
[root@user1 ~]:507# kill -9 1689
[root@user1 ~]:508# kill -9 1690
[root@user1 ~]:509# kill -9 1691
[root@user1 ~]:510# kill -9 1692
[root@user1 ~]:511# kill -9 1693
[root@user1 ~]:512# /usr/sbin/lsof -i |grep httpd
[root@user1 ~]:517# /etc/init.d/apache start
[root@user1 ~]:518#
```

しかしCentOSをrebootすると再び上記と同じ起動できない状況になってしまいます。(iptablesは停止をしたくらいで設定をいじった覚えはないです。)
Linux経験が浅いのでこういったトラブルにはまだ自力で解決できません。原因が何なのか教示をお願いできないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いたします。

以下にこのサイトで調べてやってみたこと、LAMP環境構築の流れ、大学の課題の動的webページのソースを載せておきます。

## やってみたこと

```
[root@user1 ~]:518# grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#Port 22
#GatewayPorts no

[root@user1 ~]:519# ps -ef |grep http
root      2706     1  0 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
www       2709  2706  0 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
www       2710  2706  0 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
www       2711  2706  0 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
www       2712  2706  0 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
www       2713  2706  0 16:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start
root      3033  2286  0 17:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep http
[root@user1 ~]:522# /usr/sbin/lsof -i |grep sshd
sshd     1522     root    3u  IPv4  10141      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

## LAMP環境構築の流れ

大学の講義の流れでCentOSインストール、yum -y updateコマンド実行、開発環境構築後すぐにLAMP環境構築に入りました。
 1.OpenSSL(1.0.2o)をコンパイルでインストール
 2.Apache(2.4.33)のソースをapr,apr-utilと一緒にダウンロード、コンパイルしてインストール(講義内の指定でドキュメントルートは/home/apache/htdocsにしています。)
講義で使用するサイトに従って設定を行った後index.htmlを作ってfirefoxからページが見えるか確認したところ成功。
 3.MariaDB(10.2.14)インストール。(講義の教授の指定でMySQLではなくMariaDBにしています。)
 4.PHP5.6をコンパイルでインストール。インストール後、Apache連携確認、再起動成功。 phpinfo.phpを作ってfirefoxからphpのトップページが見えるか確認したところ、成功。(このタイミングでchkconfig httpd onコマンドで自動起動を設定しました。)
これでLAMP環境の構築は無事に終わりました。

## 動的webページのソース

以下/home/apache/htdocs/
CGI(date.cgi

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo 

echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"content-TYPE\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">"
echo "</head>"

echo "<body>"
echo "<h2>こんにちは Common Gateway Interface (CGI) by Shell Script</h2>"
echo "<font size=+1 color=#c01010>"
echo "現在の時刻は "
/bin/date +"%y年%m月%d日(%a)  %H時%M分%S秒"
echo "<br/></font>"
echo "</body>"

echo "</html>"
```

Perl(date.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n";
print "\n";

print "<html>\n";
print "<head>\n";
print "<meta http-equiv=\"content-TYPE\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n";
print "</head>\n";

print "<body>\n";
print "<h2>こんにちは Perl</h2>\n";
print "<font size=+1 color=#c01010>\n";
print "現在の時刻は \n";

$time = localtime(time);
print $time;

print "<br/></font>\n";
print "</body>\n";

print "</html>\n";
```

PHP(date.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> PHP Date </title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>こんちは Hypertext Preprocessor (PHP)</h2>
<font size=+1 color=#c01010>

<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
print(date('現在の時刻は Y年m月d日 (D)  a h時i分s秒 です').'<br/>');
?>

</font>
</body>
</html>
```

SSI(date_ssi.html date.sh .htaccess)

date_ssi.html

```
<html>                                                                                                                                         
<head>                                                                                                                                         
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> SSI Date </title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>こんにちは Server Side Include (SSI)</h2>
<font size=+1 color=#c01010>
現在の時刻は <!--#exec cmd='./date.sh' --> <br />
</font>
</body>

</html>
```

date.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/date +"%y年%m月%d日(%a)  %H時%M分%S秒"``
```

.htaccess

```
Options +Includes
```

Javascript(date_js.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> JavaScript Date </title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>こんにちは Java Script</h2>
<font size=+1 color=#c01010>

現在の時刻は 
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function show_date(){
    var date = new Date();
    document.write(date);
}
show_date();
//-->
</script> 

</font>
</body>
</html>
```

date.cgi,date.plには`chmod 755`コマンドを使いました。
SSI以外は成功しました。

ちなみに講義の教授は多忙の為研究室にいないことが多く、頼るのは難しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centos には `httpd` という名前のパッケージがあるのですが、ソースからビルドした apache とバッティングしてるんだと思います。

同時に動かさなければ良いので、httpd の方を削除するか、chkconfig で自動起動を無効化してみてください。

### インストールされてるか確認

```
# yum info httpd
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.cat.net
 * extras: mirrors.cat.net
 * updates: mirrors.cat.net
base                                                                                         | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                              | 4.7 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                       | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                            |  26 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                      | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                           | 1.9 MB     00:00
109 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
インストール済みパッケージ
名前                : httpd
アーキテクチャ      : x86_64
バージョン          : 2.2.15
リリース            : 60.el6.centos.6
容量                : 3.0 M
リポジトリー        : installed
提供元リポジトリー  : updates
要約                : Apache HTTP Server
URL                 : http://httpd.apache.org/
ライセンス          : ASL 2.0
説明                : The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and extensible
                    : web server.
  :::
```

### httpd パッケージを削除

```
yum -y remove httpd
```

### httpd パッケージの自動起動を無効化

```
chkconfig httpd off
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！確認したところhttpdが入ってました。インストールのときにソフトウェア選択のところで本来basicserverを選ぶところを、間違えてwebサーバーを選択していたようです。httpdパッケージを削除したら無事に起動できました。

Answer (score 2):

エラー的には、80ポートが使用中ということなので、

```
lsof -i:80
```

で使用しているプロセスを探してみたらどうでしょうか？
80でListenしているのがhttpdだけとは限りません。

あとは、
CentOSをインストールした時点でhttpdがパッケージインストールされていて、
これが無効化かアンインストールされていないのにソース版をインストールしたために、
httpdが2個入っているということも考えられますね。
再起動したときにパッケージ版が自動起動してるとか？

```
rpm -qa|grep httpd
```

とかで確認しみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！確認したところ、自動起動を設定していたのはパッケージ版のほうでした。パッケージ版を削除したら無事に起動できました

Answer (score 1):

サービスの再起動はプロセスの強制終了ではなく"restart"を使用してください。

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache restart
```

chkconfigで自動起動を有効にしているなら、改めてコマンドで起動する必要はないはずです。
OS起動直後にhttpdの状態を確認してください。

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache status
```

既に(自動で)正常起動しているにも関わらず、コマンドラインから二重に起動しようとしてエラーになっているように感じられます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！確かに自動起動設定しているのにstartはおかしかったですね。気をつけます。statusで確認したところ、ソース版ではなくパッケージ版のが起動されていました。パッケージ版を削除したら無事に起動できました

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/init.d/apache start`で再起動をしたのですか？
恐らく起動時に自動的なサービス開始も有効にしているのでは？
あくまで`start`は開始なので、既にApacheが動いている状態で再度開始は出来ません。
`restart`か、`graceful`を利用してください。
もしくは明示的に一度`stop`してから`start`ですね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！自動起動していたのはパッケージ版で二重起動したのが原因でした。コマンドにも気をつけます。